# Have the current server time locally in the app.

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm building an app that is using a lot of NSDate class. But NSDate uses the time from the device, so if the user changes the hour in it's device the app is going to have a fake time/date and the app is not going to be synced with the server and the user experience is going to be bad...

So I need somehow to get all the dates relative to the server, I can request the time to the server each time I do a `[[NSDate alloc] init]`because I'm using that A LOT... so I need a way to always get the date relative to the server... something like [[MYDate alloc] init] and having my server time there...

The best solution I could think off so far is: When the app starts I ask the server it's current unix time, after having that response I set inside a singleton a selector running once per second updating this unix time and I change every call to [[NSDate alloc] init] with my own Singleton class that keeps my server time updated... What I'm not sure how to handle is when the app goes to background... my time is not going to be synced...

What do you guys think about this??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished by using an NSDate subclass.

e.g.

```
@interface MyDate : NSDate{

}

@end

@implementation MyDate

- (id) init{
  if(![super initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[ServerSingleton time]])
    return nil;
  return self;
}

@end
```

That should do what you are asking. As for the singleton, you don't need to check every second, that is a lot of work for the iOS device, the network, and your server. Instead, you only need to check the server once, at the start of your app. Then, have your singleton look something like this:

```
- (void)checkTime{
  self.timeOffset = serverTime - deviceTime;
}

- (time_t)time{
  return deviceTime - self.timeOffset;
}
```

That should only require checking once, to get the current difference in time between the device and the server. Then, you just subtract the time offset from the current device time to get the current time on the server.

Comment: But what if user changes his device time meanwhile ?